# Reason for adding 1 to word index for sequence modeling

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, keras, tensorflow, machine-translation

I notice in many of the tutorials `1` is added to the `word_index`. For example considering a sample code snippet inspired from `Tensorflow's` tutorial for `NMT` https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/nmt_with_attention :

```
import tensorflow as tf
sample_input = ["sample sentence 1", "sample sentence 2"]
lang_tokenizer = tf.keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer(filters='')
lang_tokenizer.fit_on_texts(sample_input)
vocab_inp_size = len(lang_tokenizer.word_index)+1
```

I dont understand the reason for adding `1` to the `word_index dictionary`. Wont adding a `random 1` affect the prediction. Any suggestions will be helpful

Comment: Wondering if this is the additional dummy word to replace anything that is out-of-vocabulary

Comment: Note that they are just adding 1 **to the size of the vocabulary**, not to the token IDs themselves.

Comment: @noe wow I just realized that. Ok, so it wont affect the prediction then. But can you please explain what is the reason to add ```1```?

Comment: I added an answer with all the information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, note that they are just adding 1 to the size of the vocabulary, not to the token IDs themselves, so the predictions are not affected.

Then, why adding 1 ?

Because [`Tokenizer.word_index`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/master/keras_preprocessing/text.py#L183) is a python dictionary that contains token keys (string) and token ID values (integer), and where the first token ID is 1 (not zero) and where the token IDs are assigned incrementally. Therefore, the greatest token ID in `word_index` is `len(word_index)`. Therefore, we need vocabulary of size `len(word_index) + 1` to be able to index up to the greatest token ID.

**Update**: note that adding 1 to the vocabulary size has nothing to do with out of vocabulary words: the words that are not pretrained are encoded as the [out-of-vocabulary token (oov_token) if it was provided when building the tokenizer](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/master/keras_preprocessing/text.py#L161), or [ignored if not](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/master/keras_preprocessing/text.py#L312). The oov token, if provided, [has index 1](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/master/keras_preprocessing/text.py#L228).

Comment: Thanks. This is great. One confusion - I read in a tutorial ```https://stackabuse.com/python-for-nlp-word-embeddings-for-deep-learning-in-keras/``` that  the reason to add ```1``` is : ```Remember to add 1 with the vocabulary size. This is to store the dimensions for the words for which no pretrained word embeddings exist.```. So does adding ```1``` serve the dual purpose?

Comment: No, that is not correct. The words that are not pretrained are encoded as the [out-of-vocabulary token (oov_token) if it was provided when building the tokenizer](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/master/keras_preprocessing/text.py#L161), or [ignored if not](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/master/keras_preprocessing/text.py#L312). The oov token, if provided, [has index 1](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/master/keras_preprocessing/text.py#L228). Adding 1 to the vocabulary size has nothing to do with out of vocabulary words.

Comment: I updated the answer to include this information.

Comment: Please consider upvoting the question if you considered it useful and also marking it as correct if deemed so.

Comment: Thanks, I have accepted the solution. You have mentioned to upvote the question, but cannot upvote my own question, please do so if you find the question useful to other learners.